# Prove if they are linear continuum

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, connections

We have this two sets $\mathbb{N} \times [0,1)$ and $[0,1) \times \mathbb{N}$ and we have to see if they are linear continuum or not.

My doubt here is that I don't know where I have to work in order to prove the least upper bound property and the second condition to be linear continuum, if I have to work with subset of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ or in $\mathbb{N}\times [0,1)$.

Well and I think that the first set is not a linear continuum because if you take a set like
$$
S = \{ (x,y) \in\mathbb{N} \times [0,1) ; x > 0 \}
$$
you don't have the first condition.

Comment: What ordering are posed on them?

Comment: We are using the dictionary ordering

Comment: Ok, but increasing from left to right, or right to left?

Comment: From left to right

Comment: So that e.g. $(1,0)>(0,1/2)$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Then $\Bbb N\times[0, 1)$ is simply isomorphic to $\Bbb R^{\ge0}$.

Comment: And why is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$$^\geq$

Comment: Just consider the integer and fractional parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbb{N} \times [0,1)$ is order isomorphic to $[0,+\infty)$ via

$(n,t) \to n+t$. And the latter is a continuum (in Munkres' definition).

$[0,1) \times \mathbb{N}$ does not obey the denseness condition: no point lies between $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$ e.g. or $(t, n)$ and $(t,n+1)$ more generally.

Comment: But in $\mathbb{N}$ x [0,1) if you take the subset A = {1} x (1/2,1) which is bounded, but the least upper bound is the point (1,1) which is not contain in $\mathbb{N}$ x [0,1) so here is an example for subset of A which don't have the least upper bound property.

Comment: @Alvaro The lub doesn't have to be in $A$ fot the lub property! If it is in $X$ it's OK.

Comment: Yes, but (1,1) isn't in X

Comment: @Alvaro But $(2,0)$ is and is the lub.

Comment: Okey perfect, that is the point I was omitting

Comment: @Alvaro $\{1\} \times (\frac12,1)$ corresponds to $(\frac32,2)$ in my isomorphism, and $(2,0)$ to $2$....

Answer (score 0):

To get a feel for this, see if you can find any initial segment for the two ordered sets. When I do this, there is no doubt that $\mathbb{N} \times [0,1)$ is our candidate.

You asked where to work? How about directly finding the least upper bound?

Let $S \subset \mathbb{N} \times [0,1)$. If $r = (n, a)$ is an upper bound for $S$, then for every $(m,b) \in S$, $m \le n$. The set

$\tag 1 \{ m \mid (m,b) \in S\}$

must contain a maximum, call it $n_1$. So we must have

$\tag 2 S \, \bigcap \, [\{ n_1 \} \times [0,1)] \ne \emptyset$

Since $\{ n_1 \} \times [0,1)$ is a linear continuum, the nonempty set $\text{(2)}$ has a lub of the form $(n_1, a_1)$.

The point $(n_1, a_1) \in  \mathbb{N} \times [0,1)$ is evidently the least upper bound for the set $S$.

Comment: But the set S is one that you choose with no conditions (can be an open set from the topology or another random set) or is one open set from the topology we are working with?

Comment: I showed that any nonempty set bounded above has a lub. Not necessary for the (induced) topological structure to come into play. All you need is the $\le$ relation.